# Store XML fragment into attribute as string using XSL

Tags: xslt

I would like to store a fragment of a xml into an attribute using XSL. For example i have the following xml

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>test1</c>
    <c>test2</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

and would like to have this result (of cours the xml in the attribute should be escaped properly):

```
<a attr="<b><c>test1</c><c>test2</c></b>"/>
```

Is this possible by just using XSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 3.0 there is a function `serialize-xml`, in earlier versions you can import a module like http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/ and then code

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:import href="xml-to-string.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="attr">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="xml-to-string"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```